# How to colorize a range in a row depending on a value in the first cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013, conditional-formatting

I would like to colorize range of cells depending on the value of the first cell, how to do that using conditional formating?
[This picture will show you what I want to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zc42H.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by highlighting just the first row, then click the **Conditional Formatting** drop-down in the **Home tab** and select **New Rule**. Create a new Conditional Formatting rule. Select "Use a formula to determine which cells to format."

Put the formula below into the field, change the formatting for the cells for which the formula is TRUE, and click OK. The dollar sign sets col A as a constant so that each row will reformat based only the value in that column.

> =IF($A1="active",TRUE,FALSE)

[image]

Once the first row appears as expected, click the **Conditional Formatting** drop-down and select **Manage Rules** Change the **Applies to** field to include the rest of the range.

I'm not sure about earlier versions, but it you are using Excel 2013 or later, you can also just use the **Format Painter** to apply these rules to other ranges.

[image]

Comment: Glad to hear it. Can you mark as the right answer please?

Comment: perfect @P Fitz done